# Javascript: how to correctly delete property from window.navigator?

Tags: javascript, navigator

Question: how to delete `appName` property ( as example ) from `window.navigator` object?

```
console.log(window.navigator.hasOwnProperty("appName"));
// -> false

console.log(window.navigator.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("appName"));
// -> true

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(navigator.__proto__, "appName"));
// -> {set: undefined, enumerable: true, configurable: true, get: ƒ}
```

Problems:

1. there is no such function like `Object.deleteProperty` (but there is `Object.defineProperty`)
2. i can not initialize `Navigator` object directly ("Illegal constructor" error)
3. i can not create new object and just set its `__proto__` property to `window.navigator.__proto__` (requesting `appName` property of new object will result in "Illegal invocation" error).

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what problem does deleting `window.navigator.appName` solve?

Comment: You can't: `window.navigator` is a readonly property can it cannot be modified. The real question is: why do you want to do this?

Comment: window.navigator is read-only, as are its sub-properties like appName.  [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator)

Comment: If you could do it, it would be `delete window.navigator.appName;`

Comment: @Terry The fact that property is readonly doesn't mean you can't delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the property is owned by `navigator` prototype you need to delete this property from prototype.

**Only tested in Chrome. This might not work in another browsers** because most DOM related objects are exotic.

```js
console.log(window.navigator.appName)

delete Object.getPrototypeOf(window.navigator).appName;

console.log(window.navigator.appName)
```

Comment: Lol, i really did not think that it could be so easy -.-

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to delete (or change) any of the properties of `window.navigator`, as it is a read-only object created and managed by the web browser.